# Template function that can take another function to check how many elements meets the condition

Tags: c++, templates, fractions, negative-number

I have function template what takes another function (class) template what checks specific condition.
It all works for int or doubles, but I don't know what to do when I want to make this work for my fractions.

```
template <class T, class F>
int HowManyF( int count, T *array, F function )
{
    int howmany = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
    if ( function(array[i]) )
        howmany++;
    }
    return howmany;
}

template <class T>
class NotNegative
{
    public:
        T operator()(T arg);
};

template <class T>
T NotNegative<T>::operator()(T arg)
{
    if (arg<0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}

class Fraction{
public:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    Fraction() {};
    Fraction(int nume, int denom = 1);
    Fraction operator += (const Fraction &u);
};

// this works
int ints[8]  = {1,2,3,4,-5,6,-12,16};
howmany = HowManyF(8,ints,NotNegative());
cout << "NonNegative (ints) " << howmany << endl;

// this not - conditional expression of type 'Fraction' is illegal
// shows in line    if ( function(array[i]) )
Fraction *tab = new Fraction[2];
    tab[0] = Fraction(2, 4);
    tab[1] = Fraction(5, 6);

howmany = HowManyF(2,tab,NotNegative<Fraction>());
cout << "NonNegative (fractions) " << howmany << endl;
```

What should I do? I need change class template into function template? I need add some operators in Fraction class? I need change a way to check if variable is < 0?

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ Give us the compiler error _verbatim_ ;)

Comment: "I have function template what takes another function (class) template" be careful with terminology, template parameters can be templates themself (template template parameters), but your template parameters are all types, not templates

Comment: Look at what `NotNegative` does (`arg<0`).  Does `Fraction` support that operation?

Comment: Also, your `HowManyF` happens to be a poor's man version of `std::count_if`. If you wrote it as a learning material that's fine, if not: know and use your `<algorithm>`.

Comment: your `NotNegative<T>::operator()(T arg)` should return `bool` Btw, the predicate (`NotNegative`) is best replaced by a simple lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You predicate is wrong, especially return type, it should be:

```
template <class T>
class NotNegative
{
public:
    bool operator()(T arg) const { return !(arg < 0); }
};
```

Then you probably need specialization for `Fraction`, or implement `operator <` between `Fraction` and `int`.